# System.Net.Mail.SmtpException: Failure sending mail - SMTP issue

Tags: .net, email, smtp

**SCENARIO 1:**
Sending mails by submitting email form on site using proper host (telnet works fine at port 25) works fine on our local system (where the code is absolutely same) as many times as we send (regardless of the time gap between the consecutive submissions). And we get back the response in the mentioned email address while submitting the form.

**SCENARIO 2:**
But when we submit the form on server, it sends the mail successfully 1st time and we get the response back to the mail address used. 
When we try to submit the form 2nd time, it fails if it is tried before a gap of 2 mins 30 secs (which is validated but not sure where it is configured) and it is successful if we try submitting the form after 2 mins 30 secs.

On server, this is the log we get:

```
System.Net.Mail.SmtpException: Failure sending mail. ---> System.Net.WebException: 
Unable to connect to the remote server ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: 

  A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not 
  properly respond after a period of time, or established connection 
  failed because connected host has failed to respond <SMTP server IP>:25

at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoConnect(EndPoint endPointSnapshot, SocketAddress 
socketAddress)
at System.Net.ServicePoint.ConnectSocketInternal(Boolean connectFailure,
Socket s4, Socket s6, Socket& socket, IPAddress& address, ConnectSocketState state, 
IAsyncResult asyncResult, Exception& exception)
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at System.Net.ServicePoint.GetConnection(PooledStream PooledStream, Object owner, Boolean 
async, IPAddress& address, Socket& abortSocket, Socket& abortSocket6)
at System.Net.PooledStream.Activate(Object owningObject, Boolean async, GeneralAsyncDelegate 
asyncCallback)
at System.Net.ConnectionPool.GetConnection(Object owningObject, GeneralAsyncDelegate 
asyncCallback, Int32 creationTimeout)
at System.Net.Mail.SmtpConnection.GetConnection(ServicePoint servicePoint)
at System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.Send(MailMessage message)
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
```

Can any one please explain where could it go wrong?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay so here is the catch:
My instances are hosted in AWS and Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud (Amazon EC2) throttles email traffic over port 25 by default.

To avoid timeouts when sending email through the SMTP endpoint from EC2, use a different port (587 or 2587). OR else we need to fill out a Request to Amazon to  Remove Email Sending Limitations to remove the throttle.

More info at: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/smtp-connect.html

Comment: Thank you, this drove me nuts. Switching to port 587 was an immediate fix for AWS EC2.